# Why Bootstrap row and column are not working with handlebar?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I'm new to `handlebar` and I'm trying to put my 2 Bootstrap cards horizontally. But it's showing vertically. Is it because of script tag of handlebar? As you can see in below image it's showing cards vertically even though I've used bootstrap columns for horizontal alignment
[image]

**Here is my HTML code**

```
<div class="row mx-auto my-3">
<!--Script for Card 1-->
     <script id="card1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
             <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <p class="card-title">Today's Order: {{todayorders}}</p>
                     <p class="card-title">Current Week Order: {{currentweeksorder}}</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </script>
     <!--Script for Card 2-->
     <script id="card2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
             <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <p class="card-title">Today's Order Amount: {{todaysamount}}</p>
                     <p class="card-title">Current Week Amount: {{currentweekamount}}</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the script tags inside the column divs to force them to fit in those columns.

```
<div class="row mx-auto my-3">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <!--Script for Card 1-->
        <script id="card1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Today's Order: {{todayorders}}</p>
                    <p class="card-title">Current Week Order: {{currentweeksorder}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <!--Script for Card 2-->
        <script id="card2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-title">Today's Order Amount: {{todaysamount}}</p>
                    <p class="card-title">Current Week Amount: {{currentweekamount}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```